# Should I 'Yes Upgrade Now'?

Tags: upgrade, 32-bit

When I boot up 32-bit Ubuntu 18.04.5 on my i686 32-bit machine, why am I prompted to upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS...which, as I understand it, is a 64-bit OS?  Surely the code is smart enough to tell that my machine will not run a 64-bit OS.

Comment: What do you see when you type `uname -m` into the terminal?

Comment: Note: if you scroll down the comments in my answer, you'll note the initial bug report on this *upgrade* being offered, then a subsequent re-filing by *Brian Murray* of Canonical because the issue still occurs..   In most cases offers won't occur, but there are still machines were the offer is made (but it won't allow upgrade.. so no harm is done).   I still see it on occasion on my ibm thinkpad t43 running Lubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: Typing uname -m into the terminal returns 'i686'.

Comment: Wouldn't it be simpler to turn off notifications about new Ubuntu versions in Software & Updates > Updates = Never

Answer (score 4):

You can try, but it will fail immediately after processing the upgrade starts. The pre-flight checks determine you can't be upgraded and display this message:

```
Sorry, no more upgrades for this system 

There will not be any further Ubuntu releases for this system's 
'i386' architecture. 

Updates for Ubuntu 18.04 will continue until April 2023.
```

I just tested in an i386 18.04 container.